# When does Tensorflow determine to deallocate the memory used for represente tensors(NodeItem, NodeDef, Op_Def...)in one session run?

Tags: tensorflow

As I know, Tensorflow will allocate 8192 bytes for a NodeItem which contain
a Node. And this allocation happens in the ExecutorImpl::Initialize()(common_runtime/execute.cc).

When People triggle a Session to run, allocation happens as well as other initializations.

I want to know whether the memory used in this session run will be deallocated immediately with the exit of this session(DirectSession).

Any advice will be apprecated! Thanks.

Comment: You can see Allocation/Deallocation events by turning on verbose logging. You can them reconstruct timeline of all allocations/deallocations, like is done in https://github.com/yaroslavvb/memory_util

Comment: thanks for your reply. But what does the number before gpu_bfc(e.g. 7-gpu_bfc) mean?
and I use tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def() to have a look about all nodes, it seems that not all node display in the second column of the output by [memory_util](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/memory_util)

Comment: 7 means allocation id, so you can grep output for something like "allocation_id=7" to find the messages. Some nodes may not need any memory allocated, so they won't be reported